# Raster Layer Statistics Producing NAN Values From Input Raster Layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, layers

I've just tried to determine the maximum value for a raster layer using Raster Layer Statistics.

However when I use the tool it produces nan values for the statistics, even though the layer clearly has values.

What would be the likely cause of this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? If you right-click your raster and go to `Properties > Metadata`, are statistics such as max, min values shown?

Comment: QGIS version 2.18.0,

Also I found 

STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=158143.61367747
STATISTICS_MEAN=29268.402562978
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0

in the metadata